# two floated divs not fully contained in the parent div

Tags: html, css

My fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yJdbF/17/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="span70">
            DDDDD
        </div>
        <div class="span30">
            FFFFFFFFFF
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  margin-top : 65px;
}

.content {
  border : 10px solid green;
}

.span30 {
  width: 40%;
  background-color : red;
  float : left;
}
.span70 {
  width: 60%;
  background-color : blue;
  float : left;

}
```

The div.span70 and div.span30 are not fully contained inside div.content. span* divs are floated divs (which are tricky).

how can I fully contain them inside??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your floats. For example with Nicolas Gallagher [micro clear-fix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) or simply with an `overlow: hidden`

```
.content {
    border : 10px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yJdbF/22/)

Comment: why does overflow : hidden work? It might have side-effects no?

Comment: simply said - the floated elements are taken out of contest and their parent element is no more their parent. Putting `overflow: hidden` makes it their parent again. A possible side effect - if you have an absolutely ( or fixed ) positioned element in that container that's not fit - it will be cut off. If that's the case - use the clearfix method, if no - you are good with `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 2):

If you put

overflow: hidden;

on your .content class, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a clearfix see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/yJdbF/21/).

**Css**

```
.clear {
  clear:both;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="span70">
            DDDDD
        </div>
        <div class="span30">
            FFFFFFFFFF
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is an awful clearfix method.. if you want to go this way you should use Gallagher's mini clearfix or smth similar. Introducing a new empty element in the markup just for the clearfix is nasty

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dyVHk8Ax is probably a better clearfix, it was just an example. Please link the Gallagher's mini clearfix.

Comment: sure, I mentioned it in my answer - http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/